# Mapping signatures to aliases in Mail.app

Tags: mail.app

Is there any way of mapping a particular signature to a particular alias in Mail.app?

I have 3 email aliases in one account so I've set up 3 separate signatures. When I receive an email to one of these aliases, Mail.app correctly chooses the alias to use when replying, but it won't allow me to tie a particular signature to that alias. Instead it always automatically chooses the first signature, I have to manually change the signature when writing the email.

Is there any way to address this? It seems like a major shortcoming, and at the moment is the only thing stopping me from using Mail.app.

Comment: Why not have the 3 email addresses as full accounts in Mail instead of aliases? The Mail folders are unified so it shouldn't behave much differently in the end, and you can then tie your separate signatures accordingly.

Comment: what @JesseP. jesse P said.

Answer (score 2):

## In a word, no . . .

Unless you can create each alias as a separate account (as suggested in a comment to the OP,) Mail.app won't be able to apply a unique signature to them respectively.

That being said, and if you don't want to create distinct accounts in Mail, you might consider using the text expansion feature of OS X.

- First, open the Mail app and copy your desired signature into the clipboard.  Then remove it from the account
- Open **System Preferences** / **Keyboard**
- Select the **Text** panel

[image]

- Click on the '**+**' at the bottom of the list of shortcuts
- Type a short, uncommon string for use as your signature shortcut in the **Replace** column.  For example:

  > ```
  > &sig1
  > ```
- Tab into the **With** column and paste your signature text there
- Tab out and your shortcut will be active
- Repeat for any additional signatures you'd like to use.

Then, at the bottom of your emails, just type the shortcut text ('&sig1' in this example) followed by a space, and your signature will appear in place of the shortcut text.

While it is not ideal, it IS far simpler than changing your default signature in Mail every time you use a different account alias AND you may find the text expansion feature useful in many other situations as well.